# Need suggestions for a very basic maze like algorithm

Tags: android, andengine, maze

I am after some help and suggestions for how I would dynamically create the walls for a level, similar to the ones used in the retro game [Tank Battalion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tank_Battalion)

I am creating a game for Android most likely using [andengine](http://www.andengine.org/), any samples would really help.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2641964/algorithm-to-generate-a-segment-maze/2643068#2643068 and other Q's on SO about mazes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a good language-agnostic intro to generating mazes:
http://www.mazeworks.com/mazegen/mazetut/index.htm

Aa overview on some different algorithms that can be used to get more complex mazes:
http://www.cut-the-knot.org/ctk/Mazes.shtml